# unable to print (char*) OpenGL strings

Tags: opengl, printing, char, version

I want to print extensions and version info available in my GPU.

I used a custom function to check the extensions taken from NEHE and even taken from the official website, and doesn´t work either.

I can´t get it working. What is happening here?.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include <iostream>    

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    cout << "test" << GL_VERSION; // WORKS . SHOWS A NUMBER
    cout << glGetString(GL_VERSION); // DOESN´T WORK. Shows nothing, but continues

    if (glutExtensionSupported("GL_NV_bindless_texture"))
        cout << "YES";  // NEVER GETS PRINTED, DOESN´T MATTER WHICH EXTENSION I CHOOSE


    char* extensiones = (char*)glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS);
    cout << extensiones;  // DOESN´T WORK NEITHER
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
glutInit(&argc, argv);
```

That doesn't create an OpenGL context which things like `glGetString()` require for proper operation.

You need to go all the way and create a window:

```
glutInit( &argc, argv );
glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE );
glutCreateWindow( "Window" );
// you can use GL functions below here
glutExtensionSupported( ... );
glGetString( ... );
```

Comment: Yeah!! i love your short and great answer. Thanks a lot, that worked for me. New things i learned from OpenGL today. ....